# Federated Authentication check box for service provider disabled\grayed out

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I created an external Identity provider in the wso2 identity server carbon console under Identity Providers. I want to add this identity provider to my Service provider API_PUBLISHER in wso2 identity server carbon console.
 But I see the option Federated Authentication disabled under Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration for the service provider. All other options (Default,Local Authentication and Advanced Authentication) are enabled

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure a federated authenticator for the external identity provider.

When you created an external identity provider, it needs a defined method to communicate with an actual identity provider like google. Federated authenticators are used for that purpose. Once you configured a federated authenticator for your external IDP, wso2is will allow you to use the external IDP with your service provider.

wso2is supports federated authentication with many popular IDPs including Google, Facebook. It also lets you configure any OAuth2, SAML and WS-Fed based IDP as well.

[image]

Comment: We are using AWS SSO as external IDP and configured the SAML2 Web SSO Configuration. Still the federated authentication radio box is disabled in the Service provider

Comment: There is a checkbox called "
Enable SAML2 Web SSO", under idp -> federated authenticators -> SAML2 Web SSO Configuration. Is it enabled?. If not you have to enable it and check if the problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Verify identity provider listed in APIM carbon console if not configure the same in APIM carbon console as you did it in Identity server carbon console. Identity server which you configured under